# heroku git clone gives fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, heroku

I got a repo on heroku and I can push and clone it from my pc in office (win os).

But when I got home I tried to clone it using the same command I did in office:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:xxxxx.git
```

and it gives me:

```
Cloning into 'xxxxx'...
remote: Counting objects: 110, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (109/109), done.
Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx: 10: user closed connection
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

my PC at home is a macbook but I can create a repo and push it to heroku successfully ~

BTW the repo I failed to clone is only 13MB so I don't think it's a matter of the size ~~~

It's driving me crazy and hope someone can help me, thanks :|

Comment: I posted a solution using Heroku's git clone command that worked for me here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32612843/490499

Answer (score 1):

The heroku git repos are not designed to be a point of storage for your app. They exist *solely* for deployment, do not depend on them for storage... ever. Go grab a github.com account and push your app there for storage.