# git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git

Detailed info:

```
Username for 'https://xiangwan.visualstudio.com': xiangwan
Password for 'https://xiangwan@xiangwan.visualstudio.com':
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 20.67 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 26), reused 1 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

1. has set `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`, still the error;
2. Only HTTPS authenticate, no SSH

Comment: try to do GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push and check the error. More info:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663267

Comment: In my case only solved disabling Kaspersky AV NDIS 6 Filter. Many network problems were reported by a lot of peoples with that filter since 2007.

Comment: DIFFERENT solution to same problem! Workaround for [Atlassian Stash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40504705/1606872)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem is most likely because your git buffer is too low.

You will need to increase Git’s HTTP buffer by setting.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2M
```

Comment: has set git config http.postBuffer 524288000, still the error;

Comment: did u solve it? I have the same error

Comment: In my case only solved disabling Kaspersky AV NDIS 6 Filter. Many network problems were reported by a lot of peoples with that filter since 2007.

Comment: I solved it with git config!

Comment: @Michael , how did you solve it?

Comment: @Jaskey Justas described above: git config --global http.postBuffer 2M

Comment: I solved with :
git config --global http.postBuffer 12M

Comment: "git push -u origin master" helped me, -u is the key.