# Git Push Error Result=56 - buffer size maximum?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I have seen many users post this question only to find the solution was to [increase the buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005259/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0).

I pushed one small Unity project (~50M) just fine after following this advice. I had to increase the buffer size to 1M, but I was successful.

My second Unity project (~75M) isn't much bigger, but  I got this same error even when I increased the buffer size all the way to a seemingly absurd 512M.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I know this error gets reported *a lot* so please mark this as a duplicate if there's a legitimate answer.