# Cloning using simple git setup between 2 developers

Tags: git, git-clone

We both are on Windows 7.

We are two devs who want a simple setup. Basicly I am hosting ( via deamon using tortoiseGit ) my repository and he tries to clone it with

```
git clone git://<my ip>/
```

I see a connection on my site and it all looks dandy.

The problem on his end is that, after he downloaded 100% that there seems to be an error

```
remote: Counting objects: 46, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 46 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (46/46), 2.21 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This error message is completly useless and we don't know how to continue.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed

Comment: We already tried that. Didn't work :/