# Repack borrwed repo everytime while using alternates?

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-gc

I'll ask the question first and then give explanation:

What will be the problems if my pack-file is very huge, say 100-150Mb?

What am I doing?

I have created a forking model for my organization. So every developer forks from blessed_repo, clone their forks on local machines, hack-hack-hack, push to fork.

Now, every user is pushing virtually same stuff to their forks and the objects are duplicated in multiple user's forks.

Hence I decided to have a Shared_objects_Store to which each fork's `alternate` will point to.
But [here](http://git-blame.blogspot.in/2012/08/bringing-bit-more-sanity-to-alternates.html) `Junio C Hamano` says I need to run `git repack -adl` every-time in the borrowed repo, as `git-gc` will not remove duplicate objects from borrowing repo if they are in loose state in the `alternate` object store.

Now, If I keep running `git repack -adl` everytime, it create one and onyl one pack, and it is going to be huge. Will it in the long run give me problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) or anything else?

Thanks in Advance!

> Update-1

I have to use alternates as disk-space is a problems. Also without it, backups are getting bulkier. (I have 100 forks of same repo, each one pushing same contents will be a mess.)
My server is on CentOS, the initial fork creates hard-links, but subsequent pushes from local repos to personal forks make redundant objects.

Comment: How big is your repository? Hard disk space is cheap, and Git compresses quite well (with text based files, binary files are a different stories). When cloning locally, Git automatically uses hard links to save disk space.

Comment: My problem is not the disk space. My problem is if the size of 'pack-file' increases to 100s of MBs, will git drive me into any problem? Like the link I gave in question.

Comment: If the disk space is not the problem, then why go to lengths by setting alternates? Also, I how do you share the alternates – network shares? I think this will be slow and counter-productive. Just clone on each workstation and be good

Comment: Which pack file are you worrying about, the one on the shared_object_store or the one on the devs repo?

Comment: knittl: I understood your question wrong. If I dont use alternates, disk space is definitely a problem (backups will also be huge). I have updated question.

Andrew, I am worried of pack_file of Shared_object store. (Size as in not disk-space, but, will size be a problem for git)

Comment: @MudassirRazvi: Are you storing binary files, or why are your repositories that big?

Comment: @knittl: Yes, I have some binary files, which I need. I have to add them in repos!