# git branch -r not showing all remote branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I don't see all my remote branches with command

```
git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

But then I use `git ls-remote origin`

the output is

```
e7ae5a2136ac27528cb201040f432faf29034d67    HEAD
a085ebd1c7f0477cee4bbad92810e057f5899b6b    refs/heads/bundles
c9b34c60a18278e02489a2f232604f8e1bd295ca    refs/heads/bundles_new
8eca519636f2dfe8a6b5d7f8e8021c5fc2a72fd7    refs/heads/compression
```

So I'm trying to fetch all these branches

```
git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 22417, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8478/8478), done.
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 MiB | 754.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

And it's not working. `git clone` is basically given me the same result

How I can fix that problem?

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)