# "git push heroku master" --> "remote: fatal: early EOF"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Node.js app, I tried

```
git push heroku master
```

after about 30 minutes of nothing, I get

```
remote: fatal: early EOF
```

How to fix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27829998/465974 could be the fix