# Git connection reset by peer

Tags: git

I have a repository on my Windows and use "git daemon --base-path=C:/source/ --export-all" to allow my Mac to clone this repository. For some reasons, I can't do git pull anymore. The output would look like below.

```
remote: Counting objects: 113, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (113/113), done.
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have tried to ping on each way, everything works. I have set bigger memory for git as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed), nothing changes.

Comment: Did you try testing the connection any other way? Do you have anything interesting in sshd log (you may have to up log level and retry)?

Comment: it turns out there were some other apps using the resource I was trying to pull

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. Is because some other Apps were using some picture in the repository