# Git remote update failing

Tags: git, vpn, git-pull, git-remote

I've been repeatedly trying to make this error pass by luck. But after more than 100+ attempts, still no progress on this.

Little background here, the origin is hosted by a private server (need VPN connection, which has an average speed of <5Kbps). Trying to sync my local with remote with file difference of more 60K+ objects. All attempts to do either `git remote update` or `git pull` always return this error.

```
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 71130, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22707/22707), done.
packet_write_wait: Connection to <VPN IP>: Broken pipe KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
error: Could not fetch origin
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
error: failed to run reflog
```

Note: Using mintty by SourceTree (running on Windows environment).

I've even added a global git configuration, `http.postbuffer=524288000`
 and still no progress. I've also tried copying from an updated local git from a different terminal, but getting a weird behavior of requiring me to sync more than 50K+ objects always.

Any comment or suggestion is very much accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a very very slow connection you have to increase your timeout

```
# Edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config Or ~/.ssh/config depending on your OS
# and set the connection timeout to long value
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 1200

# Also set the keep alive flag
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Comment: Should I invoke a `git remote update` or `git pull` after creating the config file (~/.ssh/config)?

Comment: do a git remote fetch --all --prune && git pull

Comment: Still experiencing `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`.