# Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin via git

Tags: cordova, meteor, plugins

I'm running meteor project on Windows 8.1, while trying to run project on emulator, I first check availability of attached device via command **adb devices** in my webstorm terminal and result is:

```
D:\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

now when I run project via command **meteor run android**, following Errors occured:

```
D:\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile>meteor run android
```

```html
[[[[[ ~\D\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile ]]]]]


=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
% apple-ios version check failed ("D:\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\ios\cordova\apple_ios_version"), continuing anyways.
% apple-ios version check failed ("D:\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\ios\cordova\apple_ios_version"), continuing anyways.
% apple-xcode version check failed ("D:\WebstormProjects\geo_mobile\meteormobile\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\ios\cordova\apple_xcode_version"), continuing anyways.
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git#b3270c85a30135d16ffcfa696a3d2dbeb60aa156 to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git via git.
   Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
   Error: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe: Command failed with exit code 128 Error output:
   Cloning into 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1462798663667'...
   fatal: early EOF
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   fatal: index-pack failed
   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help
   diagnose the issue.)

C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_ser
ver.js:116
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

I'm stuck on it, any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could be a possible connection issue. Are you able to access this link in your browser - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#b3270c85a30135d16ffcfa696a3d2dbeb60aa156? If problem persists, try reinstalling the facebook cordova plugin

Comment: yes this link opens in browser, how can I uninstall plugin?

Comment: And as suggested by the Meteor prompt, try it with the `--verbose` option to get more information.

Comment: @Ovais_Siddiqui to remove plugin use the following command - "cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4"

Comment: ok thanks @Gandhi I'll try it.

Comment: @MasterAM I was trying it but it gave the same info as I posted above

Comment: @Ovais_Siddiqui Keep us posted. Gud luck

Comment: Maybe [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21277806/268093) will help.