# How to fix git error broken link from commit to tree?

Tags: git, gerrit, jgit

When ever we clone the repo, below error is thrown. To fix this issue, when we tried to run the git fsck throwed broken link message. How can we get rid of this broken links ?

gerrit version 2.12.2

```
fatal: internal server error
remote: internal server error 
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

---

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2223/2223), done.
broken link from  commit b8120ef39ba5b162e77add965c81023d74c601f0
              to    tree 226b5a163f097489013123b6fdc77daead1301bd
dangling blob 67067e6d9ba29e54363f5349961bb1cc386413ad
missing tree  226b5a163f097489013123b6fdc77daead1301bd
dangling blob 201f56714b67fb6c6432fc749bddf6ba87f7b8c7
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solution presented here: [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) ? What is your git version?

Basically these broken links errors *might* safely be ignored, they are references to objects that no longer exist. Running a garbage collection with `git gc` might solve the issue too (at least the one presented with `git fsck`).

Comment: Did you try do run `git gc` on git server side ?