# Bitbucket cannot clone repository "fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed"

Tags: git, bitbucket, fatal-error, git-clone

I am trying to clone my repository using `ssh` from `bitbucket` but whenever i clone the repository i get:

```
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

During cloning repositories of `small size` it gets cloned but when cloning `bigger size` repositories gives the error.
I also have tried this method:

[fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

but no luck. Could any one help with the issue?

**Note:**

`Http` cloning works fine, but that doesn't work in my scenario. I need to clone using only `ssh`.

Comment: You can check the help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: @JannieT as I have already told the method doesn't work. How does it becomes duplicate of that  issue?? Also this post has been here for almost 6 months from now..

Comment: I suspect you are having network issues. Your paste of the output is missing parts. How far did it get with `Receiving objects`? What was the download speed before it stoped? To find out if it is a network issue: Does this work on another network? Does it work to download big files from Bitbucket, e.g. the zip file of the repo content? Does downloading big files from elsewhere work?

Comment: Try adding `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1` to the front of your clone command: `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone ...`.  This will print extra information about what is happening at the network level and may give some insight into what is actually failing.

Comment: any solution so far? I'm in the same stage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed didn't work for me either?

Answer (score 1):

The index pack failed because something interrupted the SSH session. Based on the first line of your posted error (`Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.00 KiB/s`) I'd suspect that something is blocking outbound port 22 connections. That would also explain why HTTPS works; very few firewalls restrict outbound ports 80 or 443.

Are you able to get anything back from `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` from that specific account on that specific machine?

(Sorry for the necro, but this popped up as "unanswered", and while a couple comments address the possibility of network issues, none of the answers do.)

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue running: "git fetch origin"

Comment: `fetch` wouldn't work, because repository is not cloned yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using following command in linux.

```
git fetch origin
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the methods in OPs linked post ([fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)). I'm also on bitbucket and these also did not work for me. I found the only solution was to downgrade your git version.

I was previously using 2.39.1.windows.2 and downgraded to 2.31.1.windows.1. I did not try any other versions, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening due to compression issue. So, first turn off compression:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Next, let's do a partial clone to truncate the amount of info coming down:

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>
```

If that works, go into the new directory and retrieve the rest of the clone:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

or, alternatively,

```
git fetch --depth=2147483647
```

Now, do a regular pull:

```
git pull --all
```

I ran into a similar problem and this helped me. Hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score -1):

Run `git config --global core.compression 9` before `git clone git@bitbucket.org:******/*******.git`

Comment: Have you actually tested this before posting it here?

Answer (score -3):

check this https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

git clone <repository>
```

Comment: The poster is interested in making this work for ssh, so the http post buffer doesn't factor into this.