# git pulls The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

```
app-liuhl@androidos:~/android/nwd_app_release$ pulls 
remote: Counting objects: 171, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (128/128), done. 
Write failed: Broken pipe41/131), 2.32 MiB | 1.07 MiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly       
fatal: early EOF 
fatal: index-pack failed 
app-liuhl@androidos:~/android/nwd_app_release$
```

Comment: Format your question. It's not readable as it should be on the console. Is your internet connection stable? Does this happens for other repos also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)