# Git push, error early EOF unpack-objects abnormal exit

Tags: git, git-push

when I tried push some commits by a remote bare and I received this error:

`$ git push serve_prod homol:prod
Multiprodutos@0.0.0.0 password:
Counting objects: 89, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (89/89), 98.02 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 89 (delta 66), reused 70 (delta 48)
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To 0.0.0.0:C:/multiprodutos/web/repo/ui-multiprodutos-web.git
 ! [remote rejected] homol -> prod (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'Multiprodutos@0.0.0.0:C:/multiprodutos/web/repo/ui-multiprodutos-web.git'`

How to fix it? Someone know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: Hi, I saw this question, I even tried solve my problem with question, but this not the same error.