# git cloning issue Git failed with a fatal error.early EOFindex-pack failed

Tags: git, bitbucket, cloning

when I am cloning the repo from bitbucket, I am getting below error
Git failed with a fatal error.early EOFindex-pack failed.This error is occurring end of the loading of the all objects.

can you guys let me know if any solution for this.

Comment: What's the question related with VSTS? If it's not related with VSTS, please remove the tag to make the category correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed