# Issues when cloning a repo from git: Bad file descriptor and index-pack failed

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to using git. I tried to clone a repo from git today and I got the following errors:

fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
fatal: index-pack failed

I cloned this repo before and everything worked fine. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just started getting the same issue, the answer to a similar question didn't help me though... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed