# Github Desktop. Remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: c++, github, unreal-engine4, github-desktop

I am using github desktop and the website. no git code, and I created a repository for my unreal engine 4 c++ project. I then try to publish the repository to github but I get this error

[image]

I have seen many posts with this error but none that use github desktop, just git code and it is not what im using.
I use windows, and also I cannot clone unreal engine c++ repositories either that I created at the college PCs.

thats the best I can ask sorry if my question is vague

error when publishing repository:

```
`https://pastebin.com/Rzdfbrwp`
```

error when cloning a repository from github (repository made in college pc)

```
`https://pastebin.com/72S18rD5`
```

Comment: Have you tried it again afterwards?

Comment: yeah I keep trying and it gets stuck at a certain percentage like 65%. then on my laptop it gets stuck at 23% everytime in both. so its gotta do with something im doing wrong. for pushing its different but i get the same error

Comment: Since you tagged this both C++ and Unreal Engine: does it work with other languages and non-UE projects?

Comment: I have a visual studio project and a unity c# project and they worked fine so thats why I was confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the internet I was using had protection on some websites because of the house policies of a student house. because of this it was messing up with big repositories and stopping the cloning. 
not a github problem just figured it was the internet since it works fine in other internet. thank you all for you help it was my bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the repository with ssh.

Run the following command and remove your repository:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then, try the command below and push afterwards:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
```

Comment: hello thanks for answering, where do I run this command? im new to github sorry

Comment: You should use **Git Shell** if you have Github Desktop installed, just press windows button and search for it

Comment: hello I have download git since i couldnt find the git shell. so I ran the commands in the order you said even remove the repository, but it just gave me another error like: the repository was archived. I think im doing it wrong.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot taken from Github Desktop and error messages?

Comment: I have edited my post with 2 pastebin links so you can see the full errors on my github desktop. sorry for bothering you so much by the way, you are really helping me out here

Comment: It's fine, no worries. Check this answer for the cloning part : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479/7977464

Comment: What I dont get is why my c# projects and unity one clone completely fine but the unreal engine 4 one doesnt at all. I downloaded git to use the commands but I dont even think its working or maybe its not hooked up the command line for github dekstop to git. im not sure