# git clone a a very big repository from github using ssh failed. fatal: early EOF the remote end hung up unexpectedly index-pack failed

Tags: git

TortoiseGit 2.7.0.0 
git version 2.20.1.windows.1 
I set TortoiseGit->Settings->Network->SSH->-SSH Client to D:\SoftwareInstalls\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe

I have two repositories A and B .A is a very big repository and B is a small repository. 
I tried to clone A and B using TortoiseGit on the same PC computer. 
git@github.com:xxx/A.git 
git@github.com:xxx/B.git 
only B.git is succeeded and A.git is failed with following error message:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "git@github.com:xxx/A.git" "E:\git_code\A"

Cloning into 'E:\git_code\ADX'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Connection reset by 13.229.188.59 port 22
fatal: early EOF
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (30735234 ms @ 2019/3/2 23:47:18)
```

Comment: This may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed