# git clone fails with "ssh_dispatch_run_fatal"

Tags: git

I have configured ssh key, but I still can't git clone successfully. The error message is:

```
git clone git@gitlab.alibaba-inc.com:alimail-frontend/ragusa.git
Cloning into 'ragusa'...
remote: Counting objects: 108885, done.
Corrupted MAC on input. (76220/108885), 19.05 MiB | 7.62 MiB/s
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 100.67.155.102 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I don't know how to fix it. Is it something wrong with git configure?

Comment: It's more likely that TCP offload is a problem. Try disabling TCP checksum offload.

Comment: Could you give me some advice on how to disable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+index-pack+failed

Answer (score 1):

```
Cloning into 'cacovid_website'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2983, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (448/448), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (307/307), done.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 140.82.121.4 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

It is likely to be a poor network connectivity issue. I have similar error while cloning a repository from Github using ssh