# Cannot clone a particular repo from code-commit

Tags: git, clearlinux

I have two repositories in code-commit, I am able to clone one them, not the other from clearlinux git.

```
Connection to git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: No, I tried all. Its the first time I am facing this issue. I can clone those repos form my mac, but this is on clearlinux

Comment: Finally I was able to from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed