# Cloning GitHub Repo over WSL Fails

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-clone

OS: Windows 10 Pro
VM: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I am trying to clone a repo I forked (freeCodeCamp - if it matters), on my WSL, but it keeps failing with this error:

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

- I have tried increasing the buffer size through Git.
- I have tried changing to WSL 1 (2 is currently my default).
- I have tried increasing my packet size through Git.
- I have tried cloning through SSH (this is not working due to my poor attempts to set up the handshake)
- I have managed to clone a much smaller repo.

Does anyone have more ideas?

Comment: If the URL is correct (that is, you're using an HTTPS URL and not an HTTP one), then this is a network problem.  Are you using a firewall or antivirus other than the one built into Windows?  Are you using a SSL or MITM proxy?  If so, does uninstalling all of that and restarting fix it?

Comment: Only firewall and antivirus is the built-in one. After disabling it, same error occurred. No proxies. I heard some people had success with running `git clone` over ethernet connection, but that made no difference for me. I frequently run git commands to do with this repo on this laptop. It is just an issue when trying through the Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following most of this post: https://devopscube.com/gnutls-handshake-failed-aws-codecommit/

I was able to resolve the problem. The only differences were the versions used, and I did not complete the final step. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using the latest 2.26.2 Git version available (even in Ubuntu 18.04 VM, [upgrading Git through ppa](http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/))

Second, if the issue persists, check if one of the [settings of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068021/6309) helps.
Doing a shallow clone, to reduce the history, might help if the freeCodeCamps repo is a giant one.

Comment: Thank you, for this, but I get the same error. I have been trying to do shallow clones.

Comment: @Sky020 With Git 2.26.2 on Ubuntu?