# Can no longer git clone large repos via HTTPS since installing Big Sur

Tags: git, macos-big-sur

Whenever I try to clone large repos, this is what happens:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry.git
Cloning into 'berry'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 60762, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1155/1155), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (588/588), done.
Receiving objects:   5% (3454/60762), 13.86 MiB | 4.60 MiB/ (etc etc)
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I have no anti-virus installed, and I'm not on a VPN. I tried connecting to another network and that didn't solve it, so there must be something with Big Sur causing this. I'm not sure what else to try.

macOS 11.4, APFS+ filesystem, git 2.31.1

I've already tried changing compression settings, messing with pack size settings, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) did not help either. I'm posting this because I've tried everything else I've seen on the Internet so far and nothing has worked.

Comment: can you be more specific on the OS, the file system, the git version, you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: @OznOg I don't think it does. That question's answers are basically "issues with older verisons of Git" and "not enough RAM". Nothing there explains why upgrading an OS version would cause it.

Comment: did you try deactivating stuff like spoted in the post? and also that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed ?

Comment: I couldn't even get past the `git clone --depth 1` step without an error.

Comment: "so there must be something with Big Sur causing this" So you're saying anyone with Big Sur would experience this? Doesn't that seem improbable somehow?

Comment: @matt "So you're saying anyone with Big Sur would experience this?" No. It's perfectly plausible that Big Sur changed something that broke Git in some setups but not others. Similar bugs happen all the time.

Comment: @matt See my answer. Apparently something changed with ulimit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

**TL;DR: `ulimit` was limiting max file size on my filesystem. Why this was never an issue in Catalina, who knows.**

I had this in my shell startup script:

```
ulimit -n 65536 65536
```

That second parameter was the bad one. It was limiting max file size to 32MB. Strangely, I have this exact same setting on Catalina and it imposes no limitation whatsoever. Someone must've provided this setting and I just copied it without understanding the implications.

I ran `ulimit -n unlimited unlimited` and now all is well!

**Interesting notes on ulimit changes from Catalina to Big Sur:**

I ran this on my Catalina install:

```
$ ulimit -a                                                   
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              65536
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       11136
-n: file descriptors                65536
$ mkfile 500m whoa                                             
$
```

Look at that! No problem creating a 500MB file, clearly ignoring ulimit's 65536-block file size limit.

Yet on Big Sur, with the same ulimit settings:

```
$ mkfile 500m whoa                                                                                                                               
[1]    22267 file size limit exceeded  mkfile 500m whoa
```

Comment: I also had this error (on Linux) and in my case, it turns out it was due to the `cpu time` limit that was set at 15 minutes. Since Git uses multiple processes during cloning, the cumulative time of those processes was higher than 15 minutes and so the system was killing the parent `git` process.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment (as it's not an answer) but I need some formatting and a *lot* of space here.  The short version is that you need to find out why `git index-pack` is misbehaving or failing.  (Fetching over a smart protocol normally retrieves a so-called *thin* pack, which `git fetch` needs to "fatten" using `git index-pack --fix-thin`.)

The "invalid index-pack output" error occurs if the output from `git index-pack` does not match what `git fetch-pack` expects.  [Here's the code involved](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e42405f00ecbbee412846f48cb0253efeebe726/pack-write.c#L397-L423):

```cpp
char *index_pack_lockfile(int ip_out, int *is_well_formed)
{
    char packname[GIT_MAX_HEXSZ + 6];
    const int len = the_hash_algo->hexsz + 6;

    /*
     * The first thing we expect from index-pack's output
     * is "pack\t%40s\n" or "keep\t%40s\n" (46 bytes) where
     * %40s is the newly created pack SHA1 name.  In the "keep"
     * case, we need it to remove the corresponding .keep file
     * later on.  If we don't get that then tough luck with it.
     */
    if (read_in_full(ip_out, packname, len) == len && packname[len-1] == '\n') {
        const char *name;

        if (is_well_formed)
            *is_well_formed = 1;
        packname[len-1] = 0;
        if (skip_prefix(packname, "keep\t", &name))
            return xstrfmt("%s/pack/pack-%s.keep",
                       get_object_directory(), name);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (is_well_formed)
        *is_well_formed = 0;
    return NULL;
}
```

This is run from `fetch-pack.c`'s [`get_pack` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e42405f00ecbbee412846f48cb0253efeebe726/fetch-pack.c#L818), which runs `git index-pack` with arguments based on a lot of variables.  If you run your `git clone` with environment variable `GIT_TRACE` set to 1, you can observe Git running `git index-pack`.  The call to `index_pack_lockfile` here only happens if `do_keep` is set, which is based on `args->keep_pack` initially, but can become set if the pack header's `hdr_entries` value equals or exceeds `unpack_limit` (see around line 859).

You can control the `unpack_limit` value using [`fetch.unpackLimit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-fetchunpackLimit) and/or [`transfer.unpackLimit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-transferunpackLimit).  The default value is 100.  You might be able to use these to work around some problem with index-pack, maybe—but index-pack should not be failing in whatever way it *is* failing.  Note that if you want to force `git fetch` to use `git unpack-objects` instead, you must also disable object checking (`fsck_objects`).

It could be interesting to run `git index-pack` directly, too, on the data retrieved by `git fetch`.  (Consider installing a shell script in place of the normal `git index-pack`, where the script prints its arguments, then uses `kill -STOP` on its own process group, so that you can inspect the temporary files.)