# git error fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I have been trying to clone the aosp repo, it worked fine last week but hasn't been for the last two days. I narrowed it down to the deqp dependecy. With the however I got multiple errors but always resulting in "fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output".
Last try resulted in this:

```
   /run/me/j/d/a/deqp    master  git config http.postBuffer 524288000
   /run/me/j/d/a/deqp    master  git fetch --unshallow               ✔ 
remote: Finding sources: 100% (126764/126764)
remote: Total 126764 (delta 86667), reused 126714 (delta 86667)
Receiving objects: 100% (126764/126764), 2.33 GiB | 6.12 MiB/s, done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Comment: No sadly it does not. I tried that already. The final result remains the same: "fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output"

Comment: This is usually caused by a proxy (https redirector) that has a bug and corrupts your data. You can try using ssh, if that's available, or remove the "security appliance" that's making your network super-secure by making it not work. :-)

Comment: Just as an addition, I haven't found a solution to the problem as it just went away a couple of days later. For anyone still looking at this question, a lot of the solutions are pretty good.

Comment: I hit this in a CircleCI Orb...Upgrading the docker container size solved it for me, using the `resource_class` attribute.

Comment: same issue, did you have any solutions now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the proj is too big, try using `--depth=1`  to solve.

Answer (score 12):

I also encountered this problem on macOS Big Sur 11.6.1, and I run `ulimit -n unlimited` and `ulimit -f unlimited` to resolve this. Increase the value of `packedGitLimit` or `packedGitWindowSize` and `packSizeLimit` on gitconfig did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try to run the following:

`git config pack.windowMemory 10m`

`git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m`

then retry the git clone.

Comment: I'm trying to clone a repo but your solution suggests that you already cloned the repo:

$ git config pack.windowMemory 10m
fatal: not in a git directory

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem.

```
git pull --depth=1 {repo} {branch}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is works

```
git reset --hard
git clean -dfx
git fetch --all --depth 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Has a some problem, in WebStorm and also in Terminal.

When all resolution isn't work for me, I try delete repo folder and OS thrown warning that can't delete file and can't read them.

But correctly replace files in basket.

After download repo again problem hasn't reproduce.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem in container.
Increased memory and CPU limits.
Problem dissapeared