# Error cloning very large git repo with SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to clone a very large (40GB or so) git project with SourceTree.

Some way through, I get the following error

```
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Some searching suggests that this is a memory limit related problem. Not the memory of my system or disk, but rather how much git can pull at a time?

This thread [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) offers a solution, however I don't know how to fix this with SourceTree.

Another thread suggested that I add those tags to my .gitconfig file. However, I don't have such a file because I am cloning a new project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: This might not be a git limitation?

Comment: Follow the instructions that you already found. There is a global `.gitconfig` you can modify; the location and exact settings to use are *also* present in the instructions you already found. Also, if you have a 40 GB Git repo, someone is very likely storing data in there that shouldn't be in Git in the first place.

Comment: The *server* may be crashing (or killing off the process that's sending the repository); take a look at server-side logs.

Comment: This is not a Sourcetree question. You'd be experiencing this from the command line too.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I just tried again, and it worked. I changed nothing between attempts. I don't know why, but just trying again was all it took =/