# Cannot get whole repository Early EOF CURL 18

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

I have tried this a number of different ways to no avail. For work, I am trying to clone a fairly large repository. I couldn't clone the whole thing, so in Sourcetree, I changed the clone depth to "1". Once I did that, I tried unshallowing, and that didn't work, so then I tried turning the compression to "0" and changing the buffer to around 500mill. No changes. Every time I run any of the the unshallow or "git fetch --depth 1" commands in the terminal in sourcetree, I get the below message. My internet connection is pretty slow, so I went to my brothers who has like a 500mb down and 200up connection and tried through a hard-wired connection. Still same. What can I try? I will admit that I am inexperienced with Git and Sourcetree.

```
$ git fetch --depth=1
remote: Enumerating objects: 15003, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15003/15003), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13128/13128), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 1020 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah, I think I tried most of what was on there. But no avail...