# Is there a way to fix brew install early eof error?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Whenever I type any `brew install` command into the terminal I always get the same error:

```
==> Tapping homebrew/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 659774, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (338/338), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (170/170), done.
error: 6957 bytes of body are still expected.31 MiB | 4.20 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128.
```

Is there anyway of fixing it? (I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling homebrew and other methods)

Answer (score 0):

That is [basically git clone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed), try turn off the compression to see it helps.

> `git config --global core.compression 0`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Try some ideas in that thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed

Comment: It is basically some networking issue.