# npm update "own git package" fails - npm ERR! code 128

Tags: git, npm, bitbucket

I get an error when i try to update one of my own created package through npm. The setup looks like this,

Windows 10
Running node.js v18.15.0
Repositories in self-hosted bitbucket server

In my `package.json` i have added my package as dependency like,

`"my-package": "git+ssh://git@git:...."`

When i run `npm update my-package` I get the error,

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects clone ssh://git@git:... ... --recurse-submodules -- 
config core.longpaths=true
npm ERR! Cloning into ...
npm ERR! fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
npm ERR! fatal: early EOF
npm ERR! fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I have tried everything in this thread [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) without any success.

The weird thing is that it works sometimes and sometimes not so this might be a network issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `git@git` seems strange: SSH URL should be `user@server:...`, like `git@github.com:...`

Comment: Why should it be like that?

Comment: Because the remote SSH session *never* uses a user account, always a technical service account like `git`. The SSH key used to open the connection helps the remote server to know which user is making the request, since the public key is registered in the user settings.