# Not able to clone organization repository - invalid index-pack output

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to clone my organization's git repository via VS code but it is failing with the below error.
I have generated SSH keys via my git GUI and added them to the git hub account.

```
PS C:\Users\raval\Downloads\Office_Work\code_base\New> git clone git@github.org.com:user-name/xyz.git
Cloning into 'xyz'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1562151, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1411/1411), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (826/826), done.
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer.30 MiB/s   
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Comment: Check this post for that error https://stackoverflow.com/q/21277806/2308683

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you addded your SSH key on your GitHub account, in settings option SSH and GPG key.

Comment: Yes, you said that you added. 
Try to clone your repository with https url. In browser try to copy https url and use it to clone.

Comment: Yes, I did add the SSH key to the git hub account

Comment: What is happened when you try to clone your repository with https url?

Comment: I will try and get back