is there any specific problem while trying upgrade Flutter as my situation?
facing a problem while trying to upgrade Flutter
and this message shown:
C:\Windows\System32>flutter upgrade
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 128:
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 219 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
  Command: git fetch --tags

this message shown:this error message shown

It is preferable to paste all the text instead of showing the image of the error.
The image is not searchable or index-able and is taking unnecessary resources.

Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed/28676754
